# (Windows) Real-time monitoring of log files & regex pattern matching to trigger email alerts

Tags: windows, monitoring, log-files, alerts

Is there an application that can monitor a number of log files (text) and watch for regular expression pattern matches, then send email alerts when it finds one?  I'm looking for something that will run on Windows.

I was about to start writing a script to try to do this, then it occurred to me that there's probably already a good tool for this.  The simpler the better.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing something in vbscript to do this.  The bit of code that does the parsing was the hardest part, but overall not too hard really.

Answer (score 0):

[Swatch](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swatch/) is a venerable perl script that does what you want, but I recognize that you may not want to install Perl on your Windows boxes. I don't know any standalone PowerShell-based tools, but if you're writing your own PowerShell script, you should take a look at the [Log Parser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) COM.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I looked briefly at Swatch and the Log Parser COM, but decided to write something in vbscript instead.